# How to avoid authorizing every time with Twitter Kit in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, twitter

I implemented Twitter share app with Twitter Kit. But It needs authorization that opens Safari each time when you click "Tweet" button.
The screen (below image) appears every time.

I want to make Twitter share that doesn't need authorization, at least only once authorization in the app.
(I saw the app doesn't need any authorization in the app even I play it for the first time. It's my ideal.)

Can I avoid this authorization? or decrease the number of authorization?

[image: Authorization screen that appears when you click Tweet button each time]

**Code:**

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

   if TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options) {
       return true
   }
   // Your other open URL handlers follow […]
   return true
}
```

**TweetView.swift**

```
let tweetDescription:String = "Succeeded tweet"
let shareImage = UIImage(named:"Twitter_shareImage")

let composer = TWTRComposer()
TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn(completion: { (session, error) in
     if let sess = session {
//       print("signed in as \(sess.userName)");
     } else {
           print("error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))");
     }
})

if (TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.hasLoggedInUsers()) {

    composer.setText(tweetDescription)
    composer.setImage(shareImage)
    composer.show(from: parentViewController()!, completion: nil)

} else {
     // Log in, and then check again
     TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn { session, error in

         if session != nil { // Log in succeeded
              composer.setText(tweetDescription)
              composer.setImage(shareImage)
              composer.show(from: self.parentViewController()!, completion: nil)
         } else {
              let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Twitter Accounts Available", message: "You must log in before presenting a composer.", preferredStyle: .alert)
              let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler:{
                        (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
              })
              alert.addAction(cancelAction)
              self.parentViewController()?.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```